# Is it impossible that noun clauses beginning with "when" can function as a subject?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, subjects

> ___is impossible to tell now.
> (A) When will it snow
> (B) Whether will snow
> (C) When it snows
> (D) Whether it will snow

I found this in my homework.
the answer is D.
but C for option confuses me, because of the three-point below.

1. "when" can introduce a noun clause.
2. noun clauses are dependent clauses that can replace any noun in sentences.
3. a subject is a noun in a sentence.
   so, it may be possible that noun clauses beginning with "when" can function as a subject.

Comment: **No**: "when" doesn't introduce noun clauses (even if there were such a thing, which there isn't.) "When" is a preposition, so "when it snows" is a preposition phrase in, for example, "When it snows the kids play indoors". "Whether" it will snow" is an interrogative clause in, for example "I don't know whether it will snow".

Comment: "Typically a noun clause starts with: a 'wh-word' (what, who, which, when, where, why, how) or 'that.'      
I found this on [link](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/483/noun-clauses).
Is it wrong?
@BillJ

Comment: The so-called 'noun clauses' that your link refers to are in fact declarative content clauses functioning as complements. The answer to your original question is that only D is correct, where "whether it will snow" is a subordinate interrogative clause. The sentence means roughly"The answer to the question 'Will it snow' is impossible to tell now'".

Comment: Noun clauses not only function as complements but also function as subjects. 
"Noun Clause (acting as a subject): When Mary comes depends on her time of the flight. "  
I saw this on the previous link.

Comment: You must make up your mind whether to believe your homework answer or the link. Note that "when Mary comes" is an interrogative clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options beginning with *when* don't work because (A) is in question form and (C) doesn't make sense. (*Snows* is the present tense and the sentence is about predicting snow in the future.)

However, various phrases beginning with *when* would be possible, for example:

> (E) When the snow will come

> (F) When it will start to snow

Comment: Is it correct to say "When it will snow is impossible to tell now"?

Comment: Yes, that is another possibility.